# Outputing number of leaf nodes in a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Im trying to figure out how to calculate the number of leaf nodes in a binary search tree.

I keep getting a run-time error and CodeBlocks keeps crashing at the final return statement. I've seen multiple examples on here and I still can't seem to understand where I'm going wrong.
I'm trying to do this recursively however as i stated previously as soon as i add the function `number_of_leaves(p -> left)+ number_of_leaves(p-> right)`
CodeBlocks stops working after it prints out:

```
Empty tree has 0 leaf nodes. Answer:0
Single node has 1 leaf node. Answer 1
Crashes here
```

.

```
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef BINARY_SEARCH_TREE
#define BINARY_SEARCH_TREE

template<class T>
class Stack: public std::stack<T> {
public:
    T pop() { T tmp = std::stack<T>::top(); std::stack<T>::pop(); return tmp; }
};

template<class T>
class Queue: public std::queue<T> {
public:
    T dequeue() { T tmp = std::queue<T>::front(); std::queue<T>::pop(); return tmp; }
    void enqueue(const T& el) { push(el); }
};

template<class T>
class BSTNode {
public:
    BSTNode() { left = right = 0; }
    BSTNode(const T& e, BSTNode<T> *l = 0, BSTNode<T> *r = 0)
        { el = e, left = l, right = r; }
    T el;
    BSTNode<T> *left, *right;
};

template<class T>
class BST {
public:
    BST() { root = 0; }
    ~BST() { clear(); }
    void clear() { clear(root), root = 0; }
    bool is_empty() const { return root == 0; }
    void preorder() { preorder(root); }
    void inorder() { inorder(root); }
    void postorder() { postorder(root); }
    void insert(const T&);
    T* search(const T& el) const { return search(root, el); }
    void find_and_delete_by_copying(const T&);
    void find_and_delete_by_merging(const T&);
    void breadth_first();
    void balance(std::vector<T>, int, int);
    bool is_perfectly_balanced() const { return is_perfectly_balanced(root) >= 0; }
    int number_of_leaves() const { return number_of_leaves(root); }
    T* recursive_search(const T& el) const { return recursive_search(root, el); }
    void recursive_insert(const T& el) { recursive_insert(root, el); }
protected:
    void clear(BSTNode<T>*);
    T* search(BSTNode<T>*, const T&) const;
    void preorder(BSTNode<T>*);
    void inorder(BSTNode<T>*);
    void postorder(BSTNode<T>*);
    virtual void visit(BSTNode<T>* p) // virtual allows re-definition in derived classes
        { std::cout << p->el << " "; }
    void delete_by_copying(BSTNode<T>*&);
    void delete_by_merging(BSTNode<T>*&);
    int is_perfectly_balanced(BSTNode<T>*) const;       // To be provided (A4)
    int number_of_leaves(BSTNode<T>*) const;            // To be provided (A4)
    void recursive_insert(BSTNode<T>*&, const T&);      // To be provided (P6)
    T* recursive_search(BSTNode<T>*, const T&) const;   // To be provided (P6)

    BSTNode<T>* root;
};

#endif

template<class T>
void BST<T>::clear(BSTNode<T> *p)
{
    if (p != 0) {
        clear(p->left);
        clear(p->right);
        delete p;
    }
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::insert(const T& el)
{
    BSTNode<T> *p = root, *prev = 0;
    while (p != 0) {  // find a place for inserting new node;
        prev = p;
        if (el < p->el)
            p = p->left;
        else
            p = p->right;
    }
    if (root == 0)    // tree is empty;
        root = new BSTNode<T>(el);
    else if (el < prev->el)
        prev->left  = new BSTNode<T>(el);
    else
        prev->right = new BSTNode<T>(el);
}

template<class T>
T* BST<T>::search(BSTNode<T>* p, const T& el) const
{
    while (p != 0) {
        if (el == p->el)
            return &p->el;
        else if (el < p->el)
            p = p->left;
        else
            p = p->right;
    }
    return 0;
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::inorder(BSTNode<T> *p)
{
     if (p != 0) {
        inorder(p->left);
        visit(p);
        inorder(p->right);
     }
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::preorder(BSTNode<T> *p)
{
    if (p != 0) {
        visit(p);
        preorder(p->left);
        preorder(p->right);
    }
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::postorder(BSTNode<T>* p)
{
    if (p != 0) {
        postorder(p->left);
        postorder(p->right);
        visit(p);
    }
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::delete_by_copying(BSTNode<T>*& node)
{
    BSTNode<T> *previous, *tmp = node;
    if (node->right == 0)                  // node has no right child;
        node = node->left;
    else if (node->left == 0)              // node has no left child;
        node = node->right;
    else {
        tmp = node->left;                 // node has both children;
        previous = node;                  // 1.
        while (tmp->right != 0) {         // 2.
            previous = tmp;
            tmp = tmp->right;
        }
        node->el = tmp->el;               // 3.
        if (previous == node)
            previous->left  = tmp->left;
        else
            previous->right = tmp->left;  // 4.
     }
     delete tmp;                          // 5.
}

// find_and_delete_by_copying() searches the tree to locate the node containing
// el. If the node is located, the function delete_by_copying() is called.
template<class T>
void BST<T>::find_and_delete_by_copying(const T& el)
{
    BSTNode<T> *p = root, *prev = 0;
    while (p != 0 && !(p->el == el)) {
        prev = p;
        if (el < p->el)
            p = p->left;
        else p = p->right;
    }
    if (p != 0 && p->el == el) {
        if (p == root)
            delete_by_copying(root);
            else if (prev->left == p)
                delete_by_copying(prev->left);
            else
                delete_by_copying(prev->right);
    }
    else if (root != 0)
        std::cout << "el " << el << " is not in the tree" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "the tree is empty" << std::endl;
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::delete_by_merging(BSTNode<T>*& node)
{
    BSTNode<T> *tmp = node;
    if (node != 0) {
        if (!node->right)           // node has no right child: its left
            node = node->left;      // child (if any) is attached to its parent;
        else if (node->left == 0)   // node has no left child: its right
            node = node->right;     // child is attached to its parent;
        else {                      // be ready for merging subtrees;
            tmp = node->left;       // 1. move left
            while (tmp->right != 0) // 2. and then right as far as possible;
                tmp = tmp->right;
            tmp->right =            // 3. establish the link between the
                node->right;        //    the rightmost node of the left
                                    //    subtree and the right subtree;
             tmp = node;            // 4.
             node = node->left;     // 5.
        }
        delete tmp;                 // 6.
    }
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::find_and_delete_by_merging(const T& el)
{
    BSTNode<T> *node = root, *prev = 0;
    while (node != 0) {
        if (node->el == el)
            break;
        prev = node;
        if (el < node->el)
            node = node->left;
        else
            node = node->right;
    }
    if (node != 0 && node->el == el) {
        if (node == root)
            delete_by_merging(root);
        else if (prev->left == node)
            delete_by_merging(prev->left);
        else
            delete_by_merging(prev->right);
    }
    else if (root != 0)
        std::cout << "el " << el << " is not in the tree" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "the tree is empty" << std::endl;
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::breadth_first()
{
    Queue<BSTNode<T>*> queue;
    BSTNode<T> *p = root;
    if (p != 0) {
        queue.enqueue(p);
        while (!queue.empty())
        {
            p = queue.dequeue();
            visit(p);
            if (p->left != 0)
                queue.enqueue(p->left);
            if (p->right != 0)
                queue.enqueue(p->right);
        }
    }
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::balance (std::vector<T> data, int first, int last)
{
    if (first <= last) {
        int middle = (first + last)/2;
        insert(data[middle]);
        balance(data,first,middle-1);
        balance(data,middle+1,last);
    }
}

template<class T>
void BST<T>::recursive_insert(BSTNode<T>*& p, const T& el)
{
    if (p == 0)                                         // Anchor case, tail recursion
        p = new BSTNode<T>(el);
    else if (el < p->el)
        recursive_insert(p->left, el);
    else
        recursive_insert(p->right, el);
}

template<class T>
T* BST<T>::recursive_search(BSTNode<T>* p, const T& el) const
{
    if (p != 0) {
        if (el == p->el)                                // Anchor case, tail recursion
            return &p->el;
        else if (el < p->el)
            return recursive_search(p->left, el);
        else
            return recursive_search(p->right, el);
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Problem is here***
I've tryed having a seperate counter to count the nodes, but it just prints all 0s. As soon as i add in the number_of_leaves() it crashes

```
template<class T>
int BST<T>::number_of_leaves(BSTNode<T>*) const {
    BSTNode<T> *p = root;
  if(p == NULL){

    return 0;
}
  if(p->left == NULL && p->right==NULL){
    return 1;
  }
  else
    return number_of_leaves(p->left) + number_of_leaves(p-> right);
}
```

Testing file below:

```
#include "BST.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    BST<int> a;
    cout << "Empty tree has 0 leaf nodes. Answer: " << a.number_of_leaves() << endl;

    a.insert(4);
    cout << "Single node has 1 leaf node. Answer: " << a.number_of_leaves() << endl;

    a.insert(2);
    cout << "Linked list of 2 nodes has 1 leaf node. Answer: "
            << a.number_of_leaves() << endl;

a.insert(6);
cout << "Full binary tree of 3 nodes has 2 leaf nodes. Answer: "
        << a.number_of_leaves() << endl;

a.insert(3), a.insert(1), a.insert(5), a.insert(7);
cout << "Full binary tree of 7 nodes has 4 leaf nodes. Answer: "
        << a.number_of_leaves() << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `number_of_leaves(BSTNode<T>*)`, you discard the passed argument and always start from root. You then go down recursively and always do precisely the same operations, which leads to *StackOverflow* (sorry, I couldn't resist :p). You reach the maximum number of function calls and program is terminated.

```
template<class T>
int BST<T>::number_of_leaves(BSTNode<T>* start) const 
{
    if(start == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(start->left == NULL && start->right==NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return number_of_leaves(start->left) + number_of_leaves(start-> right);
}
```

Comment: Lol, I didn't even think about it. Edited, thanks! :)